# Crosstab Rollup Not Gathering Proper Totals

Tags: mysql, sql, crosstab

I have a quick question about a crosstab query I'm running on MySQL. I'm trying to list pieces of equipment along with the total amount of equipment for each character (labeled as Z, S, F, A) in a video game along with the total number of characters who wear each piece.

I'm joining two tables, which are the following:

equipment (id, equip, price, shopid)

charaequipchart (charaid, equipid, abilityid)

However, I'm running into a bit of a problem as characters can wear multiple pieces of equipment and some equipment can be worn on multiple characters. I used DISTINCT to manage this. This is the query I wrote using DISTINCT in the CASE statement.

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN EQID is null
   THEN 'Total'
   ELSE Equip END as 'Equip', Z, S, F, A, Total 
   FROM
   (select equipment.id as 'EQID', equipment.equip as 'Equip', 
   count(distinct case when chae.charaid = 1 then chae.equipid 
   end) as 'Z',
   count(distinct case when chae.charaid = 3 then chae.equipid 
   end) as 'S',
   count(distinct case when chae.charaid = 5 then chae.equipid 
   end) as 'F',
   count(distinct case when chae.charaid = 8 then chae.equipid 
   end) as 'A',
   count(chae.equipid) as 'Total'
   from equipment
   join charaequipchart as chae
   on equipment.id = chae.equipid
   group by EQID with rollup) as ch
```

The problem I have is with the rollup regarding the "Total" row & column. This is what happens.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Y03.jpg

Everything should calculate up to 38 in the last cell in the "Total" column & row. I tried substituting the equipid column in the CASE statement with charaid and this is my result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/snBVs.jpg

No duplicates are counted in the "Total" column (which is the result I want) until the last row (Total), where the math becomes all wrong.

I'm sure I need to edit the CASE statement for the 'Total' column, but I'm stumped at this point. Any advice on how I should get 38?

Comment: show sample data and expected result.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Try `count(distinct(chae.equipid)) as total`